# Error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5 running with java 8

Tags: maven, lambda, java-8

I am trying to compile a maven project, that is a Java 8 (JDK 1.8) and when I run the following command:

```
mvn clean compile
```

The compile throw the following error

*Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/App.java:[16,35] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)*

How is it possible?
In the command line mvn is set up with JAVA 8 compiler

Answer (score 5):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Add this plugin configuration to the `<project><build><plugins>...` section of your *pom.xml* file

Comment: To save the extra minute that took me. The plugin section goes inside `<project><build><plugins>`.

Comment: @ToniPenya-Alba I will update the answer, thanks :)